# Is there a way to insert text into a page without "Response.Write"?

Tags: asp.net

I 'm trying to make a "login information" on the top panel, like "Welcome Back XXX", so I use

`<% Response.Write(Session["username"]); %>`

inside the aspx page.

It works, but is there anyway to use the variable directly without `Response.Write` here? It seems unnecessary.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET WebForms or ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<%= Session["username"] %>
```

And if you use ASP.NET 4.0 you can automatically HTML encode the value by using this syntax:

```
<%: Session["username"] %>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple "shortcut" in the ASP.NET page syntax to `Response.Write`.

```
<%= Session["username"] %>
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
<% Response.Write(Session["username"]); %>
```

Typically you want to encode your session variables as HTML using `Html.Encode`, in case they contain characters which are not in the accepted HTML range. If you're using ASP.NET 4, you can use `<%: %>`, which is equivalent to `Response.Write(Html.Encode(string))`.

Answer (score 1):

put a asp.net label on your page, like

```
<asp:Label id=lblUserName runat="server" />
```

and on your codebehind page, on page_load event or on proper event

```
lblUserName.Text = String.Format("welcome back {0}",Session["username"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

use a label and assign user name to it

In aspx (html code)

```
<asp:Label id=lblUserName runat="server" />
```

In aspx.cs (Code behind)

```
lblUserName .Text = "Welcome back"+Session["username"].ToString();
```

Comment: I think i'll gonna give compiler error like lblWelcome is not defined

Answer (score 1):

The correct way.

1. First is to check if the value is null
2. Second because you write it on a page, use the HTMLEncode to be sure that you avoid any type of injection, or problems.

now, if you like to use a Literal or a Label, or just direct write it, is up to you. If you going to place it inside an UpdatePanel you must use a Literal.

Now, if you use Literal avoid to set the ViewState to gain space from it, ether way you need to set it on PageLoad. And it will be

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" id="txtUserName" EnableViewState="false" />
```

and on page load.

```
if(Session["username"] != null)
{
   Debug.Assert(Session["username"].ToString.Length > 0 , "Check out why I have zero user name");
   txtUserName.Text = Server.HTMLEncode(Session["username"].ToString);
}
```